# How to push an object into a MongDB nested array based on a condition?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-update

Suppose the MongoDB document(table) `comment` is

```
    _id:5ea7182e6dab0211980cbd57
    AGREED_COUNT:[],
    BLOG_ID:"5ea572301ce15d34ac1d6d2a",
    USER_IMG_URL:"1587847821116-logo.jpg",
    USER_UUID:"5ea49d8cd6e3a73f48a433fd",
    DESCISION_TEXT:"ayush ",
    USER_NAME:"Ayush sahu",
    DATE:2020-04-27T17:36:46.894+00:00,
    RPLY:[
      { RPLY_AGREED: [],
        _id:5ea718376dab0211980cbd58,
        DATE:2020-04-26T18:30:00.000+00:00,
        USER_UUID:"5ea49d8cd6e3a73f48a433fd"
        RPLY_TEXT:"sahu",
        IMG_URL:"1587847821116-logo.jpg",
        USER_NAME:"Ayush sahu" }
   ]
```

I need to write the query in MongoDB  to push an object into `RPLY_AGREED` where  the `comment _id = 5ea7182e6dab0211980cbd57` *and* `reply _id = 5ea718376dab0211980cbd58` .

Comment: Have you tried using `db.collection.update`?

Comment: You can try an [update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) using the `$push` array update operator along with the `arrayFilters` update option to specify the condition.

Comment: I used this query
updateOne({_id:'5ea7182e6dab0211980cbd57',"RPLY._id":  '5ea718376dab0211980cbd58'},{ $push: { "RPLY_AGREED" : { 'ID': userData['USER_UUID']} }})